# How to remove class when value is 0

Tags: jquery

I've been looking but could not find any answer!

I have the following code, where i am looking  if `#balance` is 0, if it is, it should remove `class="hidden"`

```
if ($("#balance").length == 0) {
    $("#Reset").removeClass("hidden")
}

<p>Place your bet! Balance: <b><span id="balance"></span>$</b></p>
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWgwee) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#balance").val() == '0') {
    $("#Reset").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

Comment: Wired, it still dosen't remove the class hidden for me? :3

Comment: Can you try edit my codepen, and send the link here? :3

Comment: Allright this is wired. Do you think the local storage has anything to do with it? It still dosen't work for me, on my localhost

Comment: well, try to uncomment //console.log($("#balance").val()) and look at your console (using chrome press F12 to see console)

Comment: There it says 0 and undefined

Comment: change your if to: if ($("#balance").val() == '0' ||  $("#balance").val() == undefined) {

or copy paste again from codepen ;)

Comment: Still dosen't remove the class

Comment: copy past and write on the bet box - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obKeXZ i'm quite sure your problem is a refresh problem..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that with `$("#balance").length` , you are checking whether the element exists or not, not the underlying `text` or `html` of that element. Since your script code doesn't remove the span '`balance`' from the `DOM`, so the expression `$("#balance").length == 0` would never be `true`. You may want to check the underlying `text` or `html` to qualify for what you are looking for.

```
if (!$("#balance").text().length) {
      $("#Reset").removeClass("hidden")
   }
```

Comment: take a look at this. You'll get an idea what i'm trying to say : https://jsfiddle.net/aadu8jou/5/

Answer (score 0):

Just do the check in your `updateBalance()` function.

```
function updateBalance(newBalance) {
    localStorage.setItem('balance', newBalance);
    balance = newBalance;
    if (balance === 0) {
      $('#Reset').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMKjMw).

First off, `$('#balance').length` will always return `1`, because you have one element on your page with `id="balance"`, so your `if ($('#balance').length == 0)` statement will never be true.

You could change it to `if (parseInt($('#balance').html()) === 0)`, but that wouldn't fix your problem either, because your `if` statement was just inside the `$(document).ready()` function, so it was only getting called once when the page loaded and the value was 50.

To do what you are trying to do you would have to detect whenever the `$('#balance')` span changes. However, you already have the new balance when you call your `updateBalance()` function, so just doing the check in that function makes much more sense.